# Automatic NTLM Authentication for WSO2 ESB

Tags: wso2, windows-authentication, wso2-esb

I have a WCF Web Service sitting on a client's IIS server secured with NTLM authentication - I have no control over the authentication configuration on that server.

I need to integrate my WSO2 ESB server with this service, but I can't find a way to get the ESB to authenticate automatically. I have successfully pushed requests through the ESB to the service with web applications, but I was prompted to provide my Windows credentials during that process - I would like for this to not happen.

I have attempted to set up an NTLM proxy on my server, but couldn't figure this out either.

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Strainy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a few components to getting this working correctly. It's hard to find it all written down in one place, so I'll attempt to provide an end-to-end overview here.

I first had to use a class mediator within my WSO2 ESB in-sequence to handle the sending **and** the NTLM authentication. The class mediator references a custom class which takes the message context from the mediation flow (called the Synapse message context) and extracts the SOAP envelope. I then loaded the Synapse SOAP envelope into an Axis2 message context object. I then used an Axis2 client along with the message context to submit my authenticated request to the server. The authentication for NTLM through Axis2 comes from the **JCIFS_NTLMScheme** class, which you can reference [here](http://devsac.blogspot.com.au/2010/10/supoprt-for-ntlmv2-with-apache.html).

**Note: you'll have to play with the logging configuration in that class to make it work with WSO2. I just removed the " org.sac.crosspather.common.util* " libraries and altered any logging I saw to use the Apache Commons logging capability**

## Create a Custom Mediator Project in WSO2 Developer Studio

Create a new project in Developer studio. Right click the project node in the project explorer and select "New > Mediator Project".

This will generate a bit of boilerplate code for you - that is, a class which extends **AbstractMediator** and which implements an "mediate()" method which Synapse will call when it comes to executing the logic defined within your sequence.

```
public class NTLMAuthorisation extends AbstractMediator {

  public boolean mediate(MessageContext context){

    //Mediation Logic  

    return true;  

  }  

}
```

## Expose Some Variables/Properties to the User

The class mediator looks for variables which are publicly accessible and exposes them in the WSO2 configuration. This is helpful before you can create a re-usable mediator which adapts itself to properties or values defined in the WSO2 Carbon Web UI. Here we need to expose seven variables: soapAction, SoapEndpoint, domain, host, port, username, and password. Expose the variables by defining your instance variables, along with their accessors and mutators.

This is all really quite useful for using the **WSO2 Secure Vault** to store your NTLM password and fetching other configuration from a system registry with properties.

```
public class NTLMAuthorisation extends AbstractMediator { 

    private String soapAction;
    private String soapEndpoint;
    private String domain;
    private String host;
    private int port;
    private String username;
    private String password;

    public boolean mediate(MessageContext context) { 

        //Mediation Logic

        return true;

    }

    public void setSoapAction(String _soapAction){
        soapAction = _soapAction;
    }

    public String getSoapAction(){
        return soapAction;
    }

    public void setSoapEndpoint(String _soapEndpoint){
        soapEndpoint = _soapEndpoint;
    }

    public String getSoapEndpoint(){
        return soapEndpoint;
    }

    public void setDomain(String _domain){
        domain = _domain;
    }

    public String getDomain(){
        return domain;
    }

    public void setHost(String _host){
        host = _host;
    }

    public String getHost(){
        return host;
    }

    public void setPort(int _port){
        port = _port;
    }

    public int getPort(){
        return port;
    }

    public void setUsername(String _username){
        username = _username;
    }

    public String getUsername(){
        return username;
    }

    public void setPassword(String _password){
        password = _password;
    }

    public String getPassword(){
        return password;
    }

}
```

## The Custom Mediation Logic

Make sure you created an JCIFS_NTLMScheme class from [here](http://devsac.blogspot.com.au/2010/10/supoprt-for-ntlmv2-with-apache.html) and have added the org.samba.jcifs dependency to your Maven dependencies like so:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.samba.jcifs</groupId>
  <artifactId>jcifs</artifactId>
  <version>1.3.17</version>
</dependency>
```

Now you can use the following mediate method in your custom mediator class:

```
public boolean mediate(MessageContext context) { 

    //Build NTLM Authentication Scheme
    AuthPolicy.registerAuthScheme(AuthPolicy.NTLM, JCIFS_NTLMScheme.class);
    HttpTransportProperties.Authenticator auth = new HttpTransportProperties.Authenticator();
    auth.setUsername(username);
    auth.setPassword(password);
    auth.setDomain(domain);
    auth.setHost(host);
    auth.setPort(port);
    ArrayList<String> authPrefs = new ArrayList<String>();
    authPrefs.add(AuthPolicy.NTLM);
    auth.setAuthSchemes(authPrefs);

    //Force Authentication - failures will get caught in the catch block
    try {

        //Build ServiceClient and set Authorization Options
        ServiceClient serviceClient = new ServiceClient();
        Options options = new Options();
        options.setProperty(org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPConstants.AUTHENTICATE, auth);
        options.setTransportInProtocol(Constants.TRANSPORT_HTTP);
        options.setTo(new EndpointReference(soapEndpoint));
        options.setAction(soapAction);
        serviceClient.setOptions(options);

        //Generate an OperationClient from the ServiceClient to execute the request
        OperationClient opClient = serviceClient.createClient(ServiceClient.ANON_OUT_IN_OP);

        //Have to translate MsgCtx from Synapse to Axis2
        org.apache.axis2.context.MessageContext axisMsgCtx = new org.apache.axis2.context.MessageContext();  
        axisMsgCtx.setEnvelope(context.getEnvelope());
        opClient.addMessageContext(axisMsgCtx);

        //Send the request to the server
        opClient.execute(true);

        //Retrieve Result and replace mediation (synapse) context
        SOAPEnvelope result = opClient.getMessageContext(WSDLConstants.MESSAGE_LABEL_IN_VALUE).getEnvelope();
        context.setEnvelope(result);

    } catch (AxisFault e) {

        context.setProperty("ResponseCode", e.getFaultCodeElement().getText());

        return false; //This stops the mediation flow, so I think it executes the fault sequence?

    }

    return true;

}
```

## Package as an OSGi Bundle and Deploy to the Server

At this stage you should be able to your custom mediator project within the **project explorer** in WSO2 Developer Studio and from the context menu select **Export Project as Deployable Archive**. Follow the prompts to save the JAR file somewhere on your system. After generating the JAR file, locate it and transfer it to the **[ESB_HOME]/repository/components/dropins** directory. You may need to restart the server for it to detect the new external library.

## Using the Custom Mediator

In your sequence, you should now be able to add a [class mediator](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Class+Mediator) and reference your custom class using the package name and class name together, for example: **org.strainy.ntlmauthorisation**.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, i found your answer. As you know, WSO2 ESB uses Axis2 for web services. You must add NTLM configuration in Axis2 config file (ESB_HOME/repository/conf/axis2/axis2.xml).

This links, describes the configuration.

http://wso2.com/library/161/

http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/http-transport.html

Comment: This is an other answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29156144/access-ntlm-secured-ws-througth-wso2esb

Comment: I think this answer add automatic NTLM authentication for you. inform me about the answer.

Comment: The first link is almost ten years old. I still tried it, but had no luck. The second link is a bit more helpful, he looks into authenticating using axis2 httpClient. Perhaps I can construct some sort of custom mediator for this?

Comment: Yes. you must create your own mediator with axis2 NTLM option. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29156144/access-ntlm-secured-ws-througth-wso2esb