# WSO2 class mediator not work

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

This is my first time to write NTLM mediator followed by [NTLM Mediator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33885605/automatic-ntlm-authentication-for-wso2-esb)

The mediator project:

[image: project]

Exported Jar and [ESB_HOME]/repository/components/dropins

[image: har]

Proxy service to test:

[image]

The mediator seems not work:

[image: output]

Line 73 throw out exception:

[image: Code]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to put jars into lib ($ESB_HOME/repository/components/lib). Delete jar in the dropins. As ESB start, it will put that jar into dropins folder. Try that.

If not you may have to add three folders as given in documentation[2].

Further references:

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Class+Mediator

[2] https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Places+for+Putting+Custom+Mediators

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be related to the mediation logic. The mediator seems to have deployed correctly since there is no ClassNotFound exceptions. To figure out the error you can add logs to the mediator or remote debug the mediator by starting ESB server in debug mode 
(./wso2server.sh debug 5005). You should debug the mediate() method. The error that you have got is thrown due to some exception being thrown in your class mediator's mediate() method.

Comment: Are you able to elaborate how to debug the mediators? I followed the https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Debugging+Mediation and cannot even find the mediation debugger in WSO2 developer studio eclipse luna (3.8.0).

Comment: I found ESB Mediation Debugger coming with ESB Tooling which support Eclipse Mars, however developer studio 3.8.0 is built on Eclipse Luna, is it possible make work together?

Comment: @SeanSun, the ESB Mediation Debugger is in a new version of the Developer Studio that works with Eclipse Mars and with the new version of WSO2 ESB - 5.0.0 (still in beta).

Comment: WSO2 mediation debugger is released with ESB 5.0.0. What I suggested here is to use remote debugging to debug the mediation logic to identify whether you have got the logic correct. Check this blog post : http://itsmaheeka.blogspot.com/2014/11/remote-debugging-wso2-esb.html

Answer (score 0):

DilshaniS' answer is correct. You have to place your mediator jar in lib folder (also need to delete the existing jar in dropins folder). Following is the reason.

WSO2 products can only load/activate a jar placed in dropins folder only if it is written as an osgi component. In your case, it is just a jar. There are no classes which should be there in a osgi bundle. If it is a normal jar, you have to place it in the repository/components/lib folder. Then, when the server starts, it creates a osgi bundle from that jar and places it in the dropins folder. Then that osgi bundle gets activated and you are able to uses the classes in it.